# Odd symbol when using XslCompiledTransform

Tags: c#, xslt, encoding

I have a XML file saved with UTF-8 encoding that I want to parse through a xslt file using `XslCompiledTransform`. The problem is however that it puts a odd symbol (See image below) in front of my spaces which causes problems further down the line (Splitting the string with space, etc.)

The odd thing is that spaces from the original xml file are working fine but the spaces (`&#160;`) in the xslt file DOES not.

[image: Hex Editor]

Here is the code I have so far:

```
public void TransformXmlFromXslt(object obj)
{
    XDocument doc = XDocument.Load(@"C:\Temp\Input.xml");
    XslCompiledTransform _datawashXslt = new XslCompiledTransform();

    XsltArgumentList _xsltArgumentList = new XsltArgumentList();
    _xsltArgumentList.AddExtensionObject("urn:script-items", obj);

    _datawashXslt.Load(@"C:\Temp\Template.xslt");

    using (var reader = doc.CreateReader())
    {
        using (var writer = XmlWriter.Create(@"C:\Temp\Output.xml"))
        {
            _datawashXslt.Transform(reader, _xsltArgumentList, writer);
        }
    }
}
```

Here is the xml + xslt file I have used:

Xslt: http://peecee.dk/upload/download/435860

Xml: http://peecee.dk/upload/download/435861

EDIT: After reading [this article](https://weblogs.java.net/blog/2008/01/11/%C3%A3%E2%80%9A-and-nbsp-mystery-explained) I think it's reading the document as iso-8859-1 but why? I have no clue

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try using the `concat` function

```
<xsl:value-of select="concat(HomeAabHusDato, ' ', HomeAabHusSlutTid)"/>
```

Comment: This is producing a correct space (I guess you forgot the ' ' between the two values), but why is there a difference between that and &#160?

Comment: &#160; is a no-break space